# How to simulate iOS app in Windows 10

Tags: windows, xamarin, ios-simulator

I want to simulate iOS application in my windows laptop. Can anyone suggest me a simulator? Since I'm new to Cameron I want to develop a native application

I can simulate Android but I can't simulate iOS on Windows.

Comment: If you want to dev iOS app on windows, you can use virtual machine and install Mac osx then install Xcode.

Comment: @vietnguyen09 works for some issues, but you can't simulate iphone or ipad devices because the IOS is asking for the hardware specification and knows that your vm is not a real apple computer. it begins to block many actions.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, that is the only way even you have a mac, you still need to buy an iPhone for test your app.

Comment: @vietnguyen09 you can test application on the simulator without having a real iPhone, but it won't have some functions like camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple only allows their tool chain to run on MacOS. There are 3 ways you can acheive this:

1. Buy a Mac: You can probably find a relatively cheap, used Mac Mini to use as a build host
2. Set up MacOS in VM: I know some have used a virtual machine and set up MacOS inside it. I have no experience with this, but I imagine it's not going to be easy. Also, I don't think it in accordance with the terms of use of MacOS to do this.
3. Use a cloud provider: You can use something like [MacInCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) to rent computing power on a Mac.